# how to get HTML like formatting in plain text (.txt) file?

Tags: windows-xp, notepad

this is html page

http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=76540&p=irol-newsArticle_Print&ID=1317909&highlight=

if i do select all ,copy on this page then paste this code into notepad i need same formatting. i want same formatting in plain text format.

is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: i think there are programs to convert HTML to TXT but I don't recall which / haven't tried them

Answer (score 1):

Copy the HTML from your browser and paste it into Notepad. It will tab-delimited so the columns won't always appear lined up but you can use a more feature-rich text editor such as SciTE or NotePad++ to adjust the tab widths and (optionally) convert the tabs to spaces.

Alternatively, you could use a text-based browser like Lynx and avoid the tab issue.

Answer (score 0):

or use a WYSIWYG Html editor such as Sharepoint designer,Kompozer or Frontpage.